# create sub folders using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file `toCreateFolders.dat`:

```
D:\main\A\1
D:\main\B\2
D:\main\B\3
D:\main\C\4
D:\main\C\5
D:\main\D\6
```

I wanted to create the above directories using batch script:

```bash
@ECHO ON

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (D:\toCreateFolders.dat) do (
set line=%%a

DO IF NOT EXIST !line! MD !line!
)

EXIT
```

It's not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Compo not working

Comment: @Compo, worked, can you please explain this part <</F "UseBackQ EOL=? Delims=">> and 2>NUL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise that you try it like this:

```bash
@For /F "UseBackQ EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ("D:\toCreateFolders.dat") Do @If Not Exist "%%~G\." MD "%%~G"
```

or even like this:

```bash
@For /F "UseBackQ EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ("D:\toCreateFolders.dat") Do @MD "%%~G" 2>NUL
```